# Dismiss viewcontroller depends on presentation style (modal or push)

Tags: swift, viewcontroller, dismiss

I did FoodTracker programmatically and here is the code that doesn't work for me.

```
func cancel(){ 

let isPresentingInAddMealMode = presentingViewController is UINavigationController

    if isPresentingInAddMealMode {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else if let owningNavigationController = navigationController {
        owningNavigationController.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
    else {
        fatalError("The MealViewController is not inside a navigation controller.")
    }
}
```

Here is how it looks in the storyboard:

[image]

Actually it works modally when the plus button is pressed but it doesn't work with `popviewcontroller`. I pushed it in the navigation stack with `didSelectRow` in `tableViewController`.

Comment: Are you sure that `owningNavigationController.popViewController(animated: true)` is executed by break point?

Comment: I finally solved this today. The  problem was in: let cancelItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: nil, action: #selector(cancel)) I just changed nil to self.